# How to read a certain part of text in python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

Hi so I just want it to read the words "Out of stock" on Newegg.

```
newegg = requests.get("https://www.newegg.com/powercolor-radeon-rx-6900-xt-axrx-6900xt-16gbd6-w2dhc-oc/p/N82E16814131778?Description=liquid%20devil&cm_re=liquid_devil-_-14-131-778-_-Product&quicklink=true")
print(newegg.text)
```

I just get a huge amount of text. I know about the [:25] stuff but idk the number for that section of the html I get back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an HTML parser, such as `beautifulsoup`. For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

newegg = requests.get(
    "https://www.newegg.com/powercolor-radeon-rx-6900-xt-axrx-6900xt-16gbd6-w2dhc-oc/p/N82E16814131778?Description=liquid%20devil&cm_re=liquid_devil-_-14-131-778-_-Product&quicklink=true"
)

soup = BeautifulSoup(newegg.content, "html.parser")
print(soup.select_one(".product-inventory").get_text(strip=True))
```

Prints:

```
OUT OF STOCK.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to know whether the string is in the text, then do something like:

```
if newegg.text.find('Out of stock') != -1:
   print('Out of stock !')
else:
   print('Not out of STOCK')
```

[Python find() method](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_find.asp)

Comment: This might not be the best way; the website might have the string in JS or user comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
import requests

#Return a list containing every occurrence of "Out of stock":
newegg = requests.get("https://www.newegg.com/powercolor-radeon-rx-6900-xt- axrx-6900xt-16gbd6-w2dhc-oc/p/N82E16814131778? Description=liquid%20devil&cm_re=liquid_devil-_-14-131-778-_Product&quicklink=true")
print(newegg.text)
x = re.findall("Out of stock", newegg.text)
print(x)
```